# Post method not supported

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jstl

I am trying to connect a form to another page using POST but I keep getting the error:

```
Request method 'POST' not supported
```

My handleNext method in the controller looks like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = PAGE_NAME, method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String handleNext(ModelMap map, HttpServletRequest request,
    @ModelAttribute("indexBacking") IndexBacking bo, BindingResult result) {
    return "redirect:/" + GameController.PAGE_NAME;

}
```

And the GET method on the Game controller looks like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = PAGE_NAME, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String handleBasicGet(ModelMap map, HttpServletRequest request) {


    return MODEL_NAME;
}
```

My Web.xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
     http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
    </listener-class>
</listener>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
    </servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>
        30
    </session-timeout>
</session-config>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>redirect.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Any ideas would be great.

UPDATE
The index.jsp has the following reference to the backing object

```
<form:form action="index.htm" enctype="multipart/form-data"
           method="post" commandName="indexBacking" accept-charset="UTF-8">
      <table id="main">
          ${page_contents}
          <tr>
              <td></td>
              <td>
                  <spring:bind path="name">     
                      <form:input path="name" value="Name" />
                      <form:errors cssClass="vmessage"
                                   element="div" path="name" />
                  </spring:bind>
              </td>
              <td>
                  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
              </td>
              <td></td>
          </tr>
      </table>
  </form:form>
```

and the backing object doesn't seem to set the name field here:

```
public class IndexBacking {
private String name;

/**
 * @return the name
 */
public String getName() {
    return name;
}

/**
 * @param name the name to set
 */
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

}
```

Comment: value of `GameController.PAGE_NAME` and `PAGE_NAME` in `handleBasicGet()` is same? and from which controller GET method renders `index.jsp` show?

Comment: My JSP form is meant to go to "index.htm", which is the PAGE_NAME of the indexController, which it does. The PAGE_NAME of GameController is game.htm, but that wont get called unitl the redirect in IndexController.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Request method 'POST' not supported

this error spring throws when following things are wrong:

- HTML form action has some URL with method as `POST` and you don't have any controller methods to handle POST request to that URL.
- missing or invalid `@ModelAttribute` in POST handler method.

coming to

> the backing object doesn't seem to set the name field here:

inside `<spring:bind` you should use `status` object like:

- `status.value` **:** to get the actual value of the bean or property.
- `status.expression` **:** the expression that was used to retrieve the bean or property.
- `status.errorMessages` **:** an array of error messages, resulting from validation

And No need to use `<spring:bind..` when you use `<form:form..` tag, both are almost does the same job, while `<spring:bind..` is used to perform some customized operations. So choose either one in `<form:sorm..` & `<spring:bind..`

in your case you can fix you problem using `<spring:bind..` like:

```
<c:url value="/indexBackingUrl" var="pstUrl"/>
<form action="${pstUrl}"  method="post" >
      <table id="main">          
          <tr>
              <td></td>
              <td>Name: 
              <spring:bind path="indexBacking.name">                
                  <input type="text"
                        name="${status.expression}"                                                         
                            value="${status.displayValue}"/>                      
                            <c:if test="${status.error}">
                                Error codes:
                                <c:forEach items="${status.errorMessages}" var="error">
                                    <c:out value="${error}"/>
                                </c:forEach>
                            </c:if>
                </spring:bind>
              </td>
              <td>
                  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
              </td>
              <td></td>
          </tr>
      </table>
  </form>
```

**NOTE:** `name` attribute is important in input element, cause spring binds bean property value using name of input element.

**OR** using `<form:form..` without `<spring:bind..` like:

```
<form:form action="${pstUrl}" method="post" modelAttribute="indexBacking">  
    <form:label path="name">Name:</form:label>
    <form:input path="name"/>
    <form:errors path="name" element="div"/>
</form:form>
```

and in Controller's GET handler method add `IndexBacking` bean instance with key as `indexBacking` to make work `<spring:bind..` in jsp like:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/indexBackingUrl", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String handleNext(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("indexBacking", new IndexBacking("Jon"));
        return "indexBacking";

    }
```

and POST handler method in controller will look like:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/indexBackingUrl", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String handleNextPost(ModelMap map, HttpServletRequest request,
            @ModelAttribute("indexBacking") IndexBacking bo, BindingResult result) {

        System.out.println(bo);
        return "redirect:/someOtherUrl";
    }
```

**Edit:** when you use `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in form, then you should register `CommonsMultipartResolver` bean and `commons-io-x.x.jar` & `commons-fileupload-x.x.x.jar` should be available to make work of spring binding or else you will get `null` value, In your case `enctype="multipart/form-data"` is not need as you not using any file upload etc.

---

**See Also:**

- [Difference between spring:bind and form:form](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8591962/1066779)
- [Spring:bind tag..](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/1.1.5/taglib/)

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks. The problem was with the form header. All I did was remove the enctype and accept-charset bits and it worked! Everything else is the same. Not sure why that would cause a problem do you?

Comment: @Jon when your form uses `enctype="multipart/form-data"` then you have to register `CommonsMultipartResolver` bean and necessary jar files also to be available in CLASSPATH to bind multipart data.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are redirecting to the url from the handleNext controller
using post method but the target controller (the one to which the message is redirected)
has only a Get method,
so change get to post inside Game controller and try again.
let me know for any issues.

Comment: Thanks, that was a good idea, it now enters the Game controller, but doesn't save the name field (see the update to the question). Do you know why this would be? +1

Comment: when you are using spring:bind, why r u binding again with path name, use it only once like below                         <spring:bind path="name">     
     <input type="text" value="Name" />
     </spring:bind>                                       <form:errors cssClass="vmessage" element="div" path="name" />

Comment: Spring bind is to map the errors to the correct field. And the other path is binding to the backing object, but I tried removing one of them and it still wouldn't work :/ I must not be including a reference to the backing object somewhere

Comment: is it your commandName or modelAttribute name inside your jsp form action tag is same as you defined inside your controller with @modelAttribute ? if thats is not same please keep it same and if still it does not work..post your complete jsp and save method in controller , will have a detailed look into it

Comment: The JSP form links to the controller with commandName, but I changed it to model name and no luck. As mentioned to @subhash above, I can get to the controller fine, it just seems to ignore the setter in the backing object. I have updated the question with the full jsp form.

Answer (score 1):

if you are using return "redirect:/" + GameController.PAGE_NAME; to another controller then specified full url path of that controller. Right now you are redirecting to same controller not in another controller.

Comment: Yeah, because I want to do some work in the current controller before moving the the Game controller. It gets to the POST method fine, but seems to ignore the setter in the backing object. The getter gets called when the page loads, just not the setter.