# Spring bind data from JSP to Controller

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I have a `register.jsp` page where I have bind the following data to a modelAttribute `userform`.

```
<form:form method="post" modelAttribute="userform"
    enctype="multipart/form-data" autocomplete="off" class="form">

    <spring:bind path="firstName">
        <label>First Name: </label>
        <form:input path="firstName" placeholder="First Name" />
    </spring:bind>

    <spring:bind path="lastName">
        <label class="control-label">Last Name: </label>
        <form:input path="lastName" placeholder="Last Name" />
    </spring:bind>
</form:form>
```

where get and post methods on the controller are:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/register", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String register(@ModelAttribute("userform") Employee employee, Model model) {
        List<Role> roleList = roleService.getAllList();
        model.addAttribute("roleList", roleList);
        model.addAttribute("userform", employee);
        return "employee/register";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = { "/register" }, method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String processRegistration(@Valid @ModelAttribute("userform") Employee employee, BindingResult result,
            Model model, HttpServletRequest request) throws IllegalStateException, IOException  {



        //(expecting the data from jsp) nothing in the employeee object :(
        //dosomething

        return "employee/register";
    }
```

Although I have used same name `userform` and the attributes name on the entity `Employee` is exactly the same, I am unable to get the form data from JSP to the Controller. I must be doing something wrong here but could not find it. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: what version of spring are you using??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the answer myself.

Since I have used `enctype="multipart/form-data"`in my JSP form, it needed a configuration of bean called "CommonsMultipartResolver" in the `servlet-context.xml`. The bean as a whole can be written as

```
<beans:bean id="multipartResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver" />
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @Ralph answer I want to Explain why you need to remove below lines from your jsp

```
<spring:bind path="firstName">
<spring:bind path="lastName">
```

As Per Answer given on this link [Difference between spring:bind and form:form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8591668/spring-mvc-difference-between-springbind-and-formform)

Its Unnecessary to use `<spring:bind>` when you use `<form:form>` because both does same thing with respect to model attributes.

here `<form:form>`  also generates HTML form markup, whereas with `<spring:bind>` you need to write markup yourself.

Also you should know how sping handles binding of Domain Object, As @Ralph mention in his answer You need to use **form backing object** and modify you method like below

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/register", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String register(Employee employee, Model model) {

}
```

**Q- What is happening in above code?**

**A-** When Spring MVC finds out domain object is present as a method argument an instance is automatically introduced by Spring MVC,with respect to domain objects  this instance is same as **instance created by new keyword**  like below

```
Employee emp=new Employee();
```

The properties of **Employee** domain object are normally uninitialized accept any parameters with same names as **Employee** object properties available in the URL query String. Spring MVC uses Java reflection to dinf out  names of properties of the domain object.

For more information  visit [Binding and Validation of Handler Parameters in Spring MVC Controllers](http://Binding%20and%20Validation%20of%20Handler%20Parameters%20in%20Spring%20MVC%20Controllers)